# Should I always keep all edges looping?

Tags: modeling, workflow

After finishing Blender Guru's both doughnut and anvil tutorials I conceived that I should keep mesh quad-only. Moreover, all edges of my final meshes were looping, which I took as a rule too. But is there such a rule or how strong this rule is? Sometimes I end up with meshes like on the picture below, where all the faces are quads, but not all edges are looping. How bad is it?

[image: Example of mesh with non-looping edges]

More specifically, should I keep all vertices always connect four other?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/why-should-triangle-meshes-be-avoided-for-character-animation/2939#2939 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99369/i-thought-you-should-never-use-triangles/99373#99373 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90787/why-is-this-abysmally-bad-topology/90789#90789 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89/when-should-n-gons-be-used-and-when-shouldnt-they/95#95 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1684/what-is-the-technical-difference-between-an-ngon-and-a-bunch-of-triangles/1697#1697

Answer (score 0):

The best way to work is having a good topology (here's why [why we need topology](http://thilakanathanstudios.com/2016/09/why-do-we-need-topology-in-3d-modeling/)).
In low poly or other situations you can probably ignore a not perfect topology.

In particolar good looping are super userful if you need to control thge curvature of your mesh.